# How to color my sidebars after centering my website

Tags: html, css

I am new very new to website design. I have just centered my entire website using this on my CSS Style Sheet.

```
.container {
max-width: 1200px;
margin: 0 auto !important;
float: none !important;
}
```

I now just have blank white space on both the right and left side columns of the webpage. These columns are not going to be used for navigation or anything like that. I plan on filling them in with a dark grey color. the white space you see at the far left and right side of the screen on this webpage is what i am trying to explain. I want to fill that in to be a dark grey but am not sure how to go about doing that. Also, i have no idea how that code works up there to center my page...but it did=). I am pretty new to html and CSS so i might have a few questions to your answers. This is meant to be a project for school so i do intend to make it look nice. Thanks!

Comment: To kickstart a website development you can use frameworks like bootstrap or foundation. It takes you an hour to grasp the basics to create a responsive websites and you won't ever look back again.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a shot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That should be the `<body>` tag that you need to style:

```
body {
    background-color: #A9A9A9;
}
```